# Err: cannot get /

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, frontend, backend

I am running into a slight problem. I want to connect the server and get my products, but somehow I can not manage to get them. Any suggestions ?

Some notes that (maybe) could help: the products file is in my react folder.

Code of server.js:

```
import express from 'express'
// importing data
import data from './my-app/src/backend/products'

//initiate express server
const app = express()

//define path as end point
app.get('/data', (req,res)=> {
    res.send(data)
})

//listen to server
app.listen(5000,()=> {
    console.log('server is live!')
} )
```

package.json file :

```
{
  "name": "ecommercewebapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node -r esm server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "esm": "^3.2.25",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: What does the URL you are hitting looks like? Make sure you have the correct port number, host (i.e localhost), etc. How are you hitting the URL? directly in the browser or with javascript?

Answer (score 1):

You have not defined the '/' route in your code, that is why you see this error.
Add the below route:

```
 app.get('/', (req, res) => {
     res.send(`Hello World!`);
 });
```

Comment: @Crazyfrog You are welcome! Please upvote the answer which is useful and close the tickets.

Comment: i did it, but my reputation is low.